# What meaning of "character" is implied when we say that a person has bad character?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does the word `character` represent in these kinds of sentences? What qualities of the person do we refer to when we say this?

Does it refer to the general nature and disposition of the person?

Comment: [character](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/character?region=us&q=character)

Comment: So does it involve a person's value system, ethics, etc., or just common qualities and behavior?

Comment: It generally means the qualities and behavior unique to that person. However, _he has character_ can mean he has "strength and originality." Also, _character_ can refer to someone's reputation. _So-and-so has bad character_ would be referring to someone's undesirable qualities. I now understand the confusion. I made a knee-jerk vote to close as general reference but now think this question should stay open.

Comment: Did you look in the dictionary or thesaurus?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it refers to "moral or ethical quality" or "qualities of honesty, courage, or the like; integrity" ([definition 3 and 4 here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/character)).